# VirtualBox WinXP on Mandriva Linux host, cannot connect to service on host from guest

Tags: linux, networking, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have had trouble getting the Linux Firefox GWT Developer Plugin working, so I figured I would just run Chrome in WinXP under VirtualBox and install the plugin there. However, I am having trouble with the connection.

Host: Mandriva Spring 2010.1
Guest: WinXP

Whether I have the guest configured with NAT or Bridged networking, I can ping my host from the guest using it's router-assigned IP number, which happens to be 192.168.0.105. However, when I run the GWT application in Linux, it sets up a service on port 8888 that I can see from Linux as either 127.0.0.1:8888 or 192.168.0.105:8888, but from the WinXP guest, it never loads any content from 192.168.0.5:8888.

Any idea why I can ping the host but not hit its Web service on port 8888?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be the WinXP firewall. If I remember correctly, non-standard ports are not open by default. You would have to either completely drop the firewall or specifically open port 8888.

Comment: Turning off Windows Firewall did allow me to connect to the service at 192.168.0.5:8888. Oddly, however, the GWT Developer Plugin is failing to connect to the GWT server at 192.168.0.5:9997.